# Codeigniter & AJAX - Div reload not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am able to display the text straight from database on a page. The thing is that when the text is edited in database, I want it to instantly reload and display the new text without reloading the page.

I am not able to make that happen and I don't know why it's not wokring. I want it to reload every 2 seconds.

My view file

```
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('home/get') ?>",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#results").text(html);
            },
           Timeout:2000
    });
</script>
```

My controller

```
 public function get() {

    $this->load->model('editor_model');
    $result = $this->editor_model->get();
    if ($result) {
        echo $result->body;

    }
}
```

It displays it but doesn't reload. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `alert(html)` in success, check if its getting expected result...

Comment: Is there an event that is triggered before the text is sent for update ?? Like click, hover etc ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timeout` is wrong to use like that

Try like this,

```
var i = setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('home/get') ?>",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#results").text(html);
            },
    });
},2000)
```

Comment: Nothing is displaying. It's blank. If I remove ` function get_data(){` it displays but doesn't display if it's there. With he first one, it doesn't display at all. Please help.

Comment: Edit: fixed it, I had an extra `}`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you. COnsider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **setInterval()**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var interval = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('home/get') ?>",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#results").text(html); // you can use .append(html) instead of .text(html) to append new data to div
            },
           Timeout:2000
       });
    });
    //var get_new_data = setInterval(interval , 5000); 
    setInterval(interval , 5000);// it will refresh ajax every 5 seconds you can use a previous line if you need to stop interval by using clearInterval(get_new_data);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The page is displaying a blank page. Nothing is being shown

Comment: Yes, there is an extra `}` at the end. I fixed it. Thank you.